# 3 monitors not working after kubuntu 14.04 packages upgrade

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, dvi

I use Dell lattitude E5540 with 2 attached monitors (hdmi and DVI), and after upgrading packages in last few days, and reboot, X won't start unless I detach the DVI monitor.

So, hdmi and laptop screen works, but when I plug DVI, it won't start.

Here is the log:

```
    
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux lechdell 3.19.0-28-generic #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 1 09:32:55 UTC 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-28-generic root=UUID=9c466f81-fd46-4a15-830a-2d08b82bfd5a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Sep 28 09:43:07 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The Xorg.0.log

```
[    91.918] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[    91.918] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    91.918] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    91.918] Current Operating System: Linux lechdell 3.19.0-28-generic #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 1 09:32:55 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    91.918] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-28-generic root=UUID=9c466f81-fd46-4a15-830a-2d08b82bfd5a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    91.918] Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
[    91.918] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    91.918] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    91.918]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    91.918] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    91.918] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Sep 28 09:43:07 2015
[    91.919] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    91.919] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    91.919] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    91.919] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    91.919] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[    91.919] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    91.919] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    91.919] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    91.919] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    91.920] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    91.920]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    91.920] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    91.920]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    91.920] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    91.920]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    91.920] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    91.920]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    91.920] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    91.920]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    91.920] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    91.920] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    91.920] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    91.920] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fa665e53d40
[    91.920] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    91.920]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    91.920]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[    91.920]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[    91.920]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    91.920] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    91.925] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0a16:1028:05e0 rev 11, Mem @ 0xf6c00000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[    91.925] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension Present
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    91.926] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    91.926] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    91.926] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    91.928] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    91.928]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    91.928]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[    91.928] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    91.928] Loading extension GLX
[    91.928] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    91.928] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[    91.928] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    91.928] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    91.928] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    91.928] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    91.928] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    91.928] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    91.929] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    91.929]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.910
[    91.929]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    91.929]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    91.929] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    91.929] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    91.929] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    91.929]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    91.929]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    91.929]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    91.929] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    91.929] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    91.929] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    91.929]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    91.929]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    91.929]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    91.929] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    91.930] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    91.930] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    91.930]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[    91.930]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    91.930]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    91.930] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    91.930] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    91.930] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    91.930] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    91.930] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    91.930] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    91.930] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    91.930] (--) using VT number 8

[    91.940] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.6 (Timo Aaltonen )
[    91.941] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    91.941] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    91.941] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    91.941] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    91.941] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    91.941] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    91.941]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[    91.941]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    91.941] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    91.942] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400
[    91.942] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx, avx2
[    91.942] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    91.942] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    91.942] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    91.942] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    91.942] (**) intel(0): Framebuffer tiled
[    91.942] (**) intel(0): Pixmaps tiled
[    91.942] (**) intel(0): "Tear free" disabled
[    91.942] (**) intel(0): Forcing per-crtc-pixmaps? no
[    91.942] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 has no monitor section
[    91.942] (--) intel(0): found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw')
[    91.942] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[    91.942] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[    91.942] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 has no monitor section
[    91.942] (EE) intel(0): No outputs and no modes.
[    91.942] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[    91.942] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    91.942] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    91.942] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    91.942] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    91.942] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    91.942] (EE) 
[    91.959] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

the lsmod output

```
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               16384  1 
vboxpci                24576  0 
vboxnetadp             28672  0 
vboxnetflt             28672  0 
vboxdrv               450560  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
arc4                   16384  2 
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
kvm_intel             151552  0 
kvm                   479232  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         53248  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
iwlmvm                278528  0 
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
mac80211              708608  1 iwlmvm
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1 
dell_wmi               16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
dell_laptop            16384  0 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
aesni_intel           172032  1 
rfcomm                 69632  8 
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
bnep                   20480  2 
snd_hda_intel          32768  0 
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
i8k                    16384  0 
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
btusb                  40960  0 
iwlwifi               188416  1 iwlmvm
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0 
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
cfg80211              524288  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
serio_raw              16384  0 
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
shpchp                 40960  0 
8250_fintek            16384  0 
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lpc_ich                24576  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
snd                    86016  11 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
dell_smo8800           16384  0 
mei_me                 20480  0 
dell_rbtn              16384  1 
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
binfmt_misc            20480  1 
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
parport_pc             32768  1 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  2 hid_generic,usbhid
i915                 1048576  2 
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 i915
sdhci_pci              24576  0 
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
e1000e                237568  0 
psmouse               114688  0 
drm                   344064  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2 
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
libahci                32768  1 ahci
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
wmi                    20480  1 dell_wmi
video                  20480  1 i915
```

the video card is intel 4400

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 05e0
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: 

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 05e0
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
        Memory at f6c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at  [disabled]
        Capabilities: 
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:A16]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f6c00000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

packages updated in the last few days:

```
Start-Date: 2015-09-21  11:50:58
Install: libllvm3.4:amd64 (3.4-1ubuntu3, automatic), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
Remove: xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.2.8-1ubuntu1~trusty1), libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:amd64 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:amd64 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), libgl1-mesa-glx-l
ts-vivid:i386 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:amd64 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.9.1-1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid:amd64 (0.9.6-2build3~
trusty1), libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid:amd64 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.8.1-1ubuntu1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.0.11-1ubuntu2build1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid:amd64 (7.7+7ubuntu3~trus
ty1), xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid:amd64 (13.0.0-1ubuntu1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-lts-vivid:amd64 (7.7+7ubuntu3~trusty1), xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid:amd64 (0.25.0-0ubuntu1.1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-vivid:amd64 (7.5.0-1ubuntu2~trusty1), xser
ver-xorg-video-r128-lts-vivid:amd64 (6.9.2-1ubuntu1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.4.6-0ubuntu1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-vivid:amd64 (6.9.4-2ubuntu1~trusty1), kubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.308.1.2), libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid:amd64 (10
.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.7.7-2ubuntu2~trusty1), kde-window-manager:amd64 (4.11.11-0ubuntu0.2), xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid:amd64 (2.3.7-2ubuntu4~trusty1), libgbm1-lts-vivid:amd64 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), xserve
r-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid:amd64 (7.7+7ubuntu3~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid:amd64 (13.1.0-0ubuntu1build1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid:amd64 (7.5.0-1ubuntu2~trusty1), xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid:amd64 (2.9.0-1ubuntu2~trusty1), libgles
2-mesa-lts-vivid:amd64 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.17.1-0ubuntu3~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid:amd64 (2.99.917-1~exp1ubuntu2.2~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid:amd64 (2.3.3-1build3~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video
-trident-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.3.6-0ubuntu6build1~trusty1), libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid:amd64 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.6.3-2ubuntu1~trusty1), kde-workspace:amd64 (4.11.11-0ubuntu0.2), xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-vivid:amd64 (0.3.
3-1ubuntu1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid:amd64 (1.5.2-2ubuntu1~trusty1), libxatracker2-lts-vivid:amd64 (10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2), xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid:amd64 (0.4.4-1build3~trusty1)
End-Date: 2015-09-21  11:51:06

Start-Date: 2015-09-21  11:54:11
Commandline: apt-get -f install
Install: xserver-xorg-video-vmware:amd64 (13.0.2-2ubuntu1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:amd64 (1.7.7-2build1, automatic), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), libopenvg1-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64 (
10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64 (0.9.6-2build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-savage:amd64 (2.3.7-2ubuntu2, automatic), xserver-xorg-input-all:amd64 (7.7+1ubuntu8.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-input-wacom:amd64 (0.23.0-0ubuntu2, automatic), 
xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu4, automatic), libllvm3.4:i386 (3.4-1ubuntu3, automatic), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64 (1.2.8-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:amd64 (1.7.4-0ubuntu
1, automatic), xserver-xorg-input-evdev:amd64 (2.8.2-1ubuntu2, automatic), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7, automatic), libglapi-mesa:i386 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), xserver-xorg-input-mouse:amd64 (1.9.0-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 
(2.3.3-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 (1.5.2-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 (7.7+1ubuntu8.1, automatic), libspice-server1:amd64 (0.12.4-0nocelt2ubuntu1.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-qxl:amd64 (0.1.1-0ubuntu3, automatic), libgl
es2-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), libxatracker2:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 (2.99.910-0ubuntu1.6, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 (7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1, automa
tic), libglamor0:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu4, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 (6.9.4-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-tdfx:amd64 (1.4.5-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 (0.4.4-1build1, automatic), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu
0.4, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 (1.3.6-0ubuntu5, automatic), libgbm1:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-openchrome:amd64 (0.3.3-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg:amd64 (7.7+1ubuntu8.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:amd64 (
13.0.0-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 (7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-sis:amd64 (0.10.7-0ubuntu6, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-s3:amd64 (0.6.5-0ubuntu4, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-modesetting:amd64 (0.8.1-1build1, automatic),
 xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 (6.9.2-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-mga:amd64 (1.6.3-1build1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 (1.0.10-1ubuntu2, automatic)
End-Date: 2015-09-21  11:54:16

Start-Date: 2015-09-22  08:24:06
Upgrade: flashplugin-installer:amd64 (11.2.202.508ubuntu0.14.04.1, 11.2.202.521ubuntu0.14.04.1)
End-Date: 2015-09-22  08:24:11

Start-Date: 2015-09-22  09:58:38
Commandline: apt-get install htop
Install: htop:amd64 (1.0.2-3)
End-Date: 2015-09-22  09:58:39

Start-Date: 2015-09-22  10:30:33
Install: libgail-3-0:amd64 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6, automatic), evince:amd64 (3.10.3-0ubuntu10.2), libgeis1:amd64 (2.2.16+14.04.20140303-0ubuntu1, automatic), gnome-icon-theme-symbolic:amd64 (3.10.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), evince-common:amd64 (3.10.3-0ubuntu10.2, automatic), li
bpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.24.5-2ubuntu4.2, automatic), libgxps2:amd64 (0.2.2-2ubuntu2, automatic), libevview3-3:amd64 (3.10.3-0ubuntu10.2, automatic), libgrip0:amd64 (0.3.7+14.04.20140303-0ubuntu1, automatic), libt1-5:amd64 (5.1.2-3.6ubuntu1, automatic), libgrail6:amd64 (3
.1.0daily13.06.05-0ubuntu1, automatic), libkpathsea6:amd64 (2013.20130729.30972-2build3, automatic), gnome-icon-theme:amd64 (3.10.0-0ubuntu2, automatic), libframe6:amd64 (2.5.0daily13.06.05-0ubuntu1, automatic), libevdocument3-4:amd64 (3.10.3-0ubuntu10.2, automatic), hum
anity-icon-theme:amd64 (0.6.5, automatic)
End-Date: 2015-09-22  10:30:39


Start-Date: 2015-09-23  07:50:50
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (40.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), xul-ext-ubufox:amd64 (3.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 3.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), firefox:amd64 (40.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (44.0.2403.89-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1095, 45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1097), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (44.0.2403.89-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1095, 45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1097), chromium-browser:amd64 (44.0.2403.89-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1095, 45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1097)
End-Date: 2015-09-23  07:51:02

Start-Date: 2015-09-24  07:46:44
Upgrade: libsystemd-login0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.13, 204-5ubuntu20.14), systemd-services:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.13, 204-5ubuntu20.14), libgail18:amd64 (2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2, 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.3), python3.4:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1), python3.4-minimal:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1), libsystemd-daemon0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.13, 204-5ubuntu20.14), libgudev-1.0-0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.13, 204-5ubuntu20.14), libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.13, 204-5ubuntu20.14), libgtk2.0-bin:amd64 (2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2, 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.3), libgtk2.0-common:amd64 (2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2, 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.3), libpython3.4:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1), thermald:amd64 (1.4.3-3~14.04.1, 1.4.3-5~14.04.1), udev:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.13, 204-5ubuntu20.14), libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1), libudev1:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.13, 204-5ubuntu20.14), libudev1:i386 (204-5ubuntu20.13, 204-5ubuntu20.14), binutils:amd64 (2.24-5ubuntu13, 2.24-5ubuntu14), lshw:amd64 (02.16-2ubuntu1.2, 02.16-2ubuntu1.3), libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2, 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.3), python3-gdbm:amd64 (3.4.0-0ubuntu1, 3.4.3-1~14.04.2), irqbalance:amd64 (1.0.6-2ubuntu0.14.04.3, 1.0.6-2ubuntu0.14.04.4)
End-Date: 2015-09-24  07:47:02

Start-Date: 2015-09-25  07:48:47
Upgrade: python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.13, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15), apport-kde:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.13, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15), apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.13, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15), python3-apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.13, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15)
End-Date: 2015-09-25  07:48:51
```